# Trying to send variables with terraform plan using concourse ci

Tags: terraform, concourse, concourse-pipeline

I am trying to create a pipeline in concourse, which is going to trigger on github updates on a remote branch, and use that branch to plan, apply and destroy a terraform deployment.

```
- name: terraform-repo
  type: git
  icon: github
  source:
    uri: https://github.com/....

#docker image
- name: terraform-0-13-7
  type: registry-image
  source:
    repository: hashicorp/terraform
    tag: 0.13.7

jobs:
- name: terraform-deplyoment
  plan:
  - get: terraform-0-13-7
  - get: terraform-repo
    trigger: true

  - task: terraform-init
    image: terraform-0-13-7
    config:
      inputs:
      - name: terraform-repo
      outputs:
      - name: terraform-repo
      platform: linux
      run:
        path: terraform
        dir: terraform-repo
        args:
        - init

  - task: terraform-plan
    image: terraform-0-13-7
    config:
      inputs:
      - name: terraform-repo
      outputs:
      - name: terraform-repo
      platform: linux
      run:
        path: terraform
        dir: terraform-repo
        args:
        - plan
        params:
          variable1: "test"
          variable2: "test2"
```

This is erroring out on the concourse GUI when triggering the pipeline mentioning that the vars are not available. Am I doing something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: I could get it to work by editing the args to contain a long string with my vars.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The `params` are exposed to the task as environment variables so you should use them as [input variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#environment-variables)

```yaml
  - task: terraform-plan
    image: terraform-0-13-7
    config:
      inputs:
      - name: terraform-repo
      outputs:
      - name: terraform-repo
      platform: linux
      run:
        path: terraform
        dir: terraform-repo
        args:
        - plan
        params:
          TF_VAR_variable1: "test"
          TF_VAR_variable2: "test2"
```